# react native doesn't find android studio and sdk

Tags: react-native, ubuntu-20.04

There are so many questions on this but in my particular case

- `Android Studio itself is giving error`.
- `Android SDK is not showing supported version`.

[image]

**In `.bashrc` I have the following :-**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
```

I moved this thing to `bash_profile` and tried but no luck. It is same.

any working solution is good. My **Ubuntu version is 20.4**

Comment: Did you solve this? 
I have the same problem with one of my older projects on Linux Mint 20.3. But I remember it was okay last year, now it cannot find the Android SDK. All environment variables are set and works, also tried with 'local.properties'. No luck.

Answer (score -1):

try to enter into android studio and go to sdk manager and install sdk 10

Comment: I followed the exact steps in react native doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup `Install the Android SDK`